# Make - How can I define a generic pattern for extensionless files

Tags: makefile

I'm experimenting with some semi-literate programming, and need to build some files that have no .extension. I'd like to use a generic patter in my Makefile, but can't get it to work.

Here's my Makefile, reduced to an MWE:

```
all: jcb jcbsetup
jcbsetup: jcb.org
%.: %.org
    ./weborg2asm.awk $< > $@
```

In this case, `make -B` says "nothing to be done"

If I try changing `%.:` to `% :`, it builds only jcb, not jcbsetup.

Obviously, I can code the recipe for each explicit target, but for obvious reasons I'd like to use a pattern. I can (sort of) understand why this doesn't work, but is there something that *does* work?

I'm using Gnu Make 4.0, under cygwin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown, this shows how to build `jcb.` from `jcb.org`, and says nothing about `jcb`.

If (as looks correct) you change the rule to `%: %.org` then that would appear to do the correct thing, and your makefile is doing what you asked.

Note that your target `jcbsetup: jcb.org` doesn't have any actions, and therefore it's saying that "when `jcb.org` is made, then `jcbsetup` is up-to-date, too", and it won't do anything *extra* to make `jcbsetup`.

If you have a `jcbsetup.org`, then the `%: %.org` would match, and this would indicate how to create `jcbsetup` from `jcbsetup.org`.  But this would happen only in this case.

Note that it's usual for the pattern rules (involving `%`) to go *before* the first concrete rule; they may not be recognised afterwards (even if they are, it's more conventional/readable for them to go first).

Comment: Thank you. I'm using jcb.org as the pre-source for everything, so I guess I'll need to add the command to the explicit rules, maybe using a `$(command)` -like construct.

Comment: In that case, you could potentially have `jcb%: jcb.org` as a pattern, and something involving `$(patsubst ...)` and the variable `$@` in the action. Vague – sorry – but this might point you in the right direction.